# How to select element without children in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<li>
    <a><span><i></i>Image<span>Description</span></span></a>
</li>
```

I would like to extract the "Image" text from the above DOM. 
If I try to get `$("span").text()`, it returns "ImageDescription" text. 
How can i get only "Image" text from the kind of structure in Jquery?

Comment: Try this  $("span:first-child").text()

Comment: @GauravKandpal That'll give you `ImageDescription` too: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/L9tp5wku/

Comment: @GauravKandpal same issue with your edit: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/L9tp5wku/1/. You need to access the actual textNodes.

Comment: Why don't you just change the HTML and wrap the Image with an element with a class attribute, which you could easily access?

Comment: I just decided to change the DOM structure as @yunzen `s comment because it seems that it is hard to catch the specific text. Thank you all!